# Cannot get basic emberjs application to work on rails platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js

I have a rails app that contains a StaticController with an index action:

```
class Private::StaticController < PrivateController

  def index

  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
get 'static' => 'private/static#index'
```

I want to start an emberjs application in the corresponding view:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'ember_application' %>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div>{{outlet}}</div>
</script>
```

For that I created a basic emberJS router:

```
PlatformUI.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('test', { path: '/test' });
});

PlatformUI.Router.reopen({
  rootURL: '/static/'
});
```

The template (in app/assets/javascripts/templates/test.handlebars) contains:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="test">    
    <h2>Something</h2>
</script>
```

When running the application, just the word 'Hello' is displayed on the page. The ember inspector (chrome plugin) says that emberjs is correctly loaded. Is there a problem with the routes? How can I debug this??

Gemfile:

```
gem 'ember-rails'
gem 'ember-source', '~> 1.9.1'
```

Update, I managed to get the transition logger to tell me I am in /test by changing the following:

```
PlatformUI.Router.map(function() {
  //this.route('index', { path: '/' });

  this.resource('test', { path: '/test' });

});

PlatformUI.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history',
  rootURL: '/static/'
});
```

The template is still not loading though. I see the script tag of the handlebar at the bottom of the page, it's not being used.

Comment: What is the url you are using to access the Ember app? To debug, try to enable logging of transitions (see [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/)); If you are not in './test' route, there will be nothing rendered into {{outlet}}...

Comment: @jesenko I am in /static/#/test

Comment: What about the output from transitions logging?

Comment: @jesenko `Attempting URL transition to /`. I am in /static/test right now. I have tried both /static/test and /static/#/test

Comment: @jesenko I posted an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not include script tags in `test.handlebars` template, content of this file should contain only handlebars template, i.e.

```
<h2>Something</h2>
```

Script tags are only needed if embedding templates into html directly.

Also, rails view should contain something like:

```
<head>
    <!-- other standard head content -->
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'ember_application' %>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Application template should be in `application.handlebars` file, containing

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div>{{outlet}}</div>
```

Comment: Alright, I made some progress, now it displays the template but at the bottom of the `<body>`

Comment: I have updated my answer, properly structuring rails view and moving ember application to separate template file

Comment: Note that if you are starting with the new project, [ember-cli-rails](https://github.com/rwz/ember-cli-rails) might be the way to go with ember-cli and rails integration.

Comment: I had to add a `rootElement` parameter when I created the Application, I wish somebody told me that..